# I am getting error in my cart.php page

Tags: php, mysql

Why am i getting this error in my `cart.php`

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function money_format() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\link\onlinestore\cart.php on line 112"

**cart.php:**

```
<?php 

  session_start(); 

  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');   include
  "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";  ?> <?php 

  if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
      $pid = $_POST['pid'];     $wasFound = false;  $i = 0;

    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"])
  < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET      $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));    } else {        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT      foreach
  ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] +
  1)));
                      $wasFound = true;
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
           } // close foreach loop
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
           }    }   header("location: cart.php"); 
      exit(); } 
?> 
<?php 

  if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
      unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]); } 
?> 
<?php 


  if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "")
  {
      // execute some code  $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];     $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];     $quantity =
  preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but
  numbers   if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }   if ($quantity < 1)
  { $quantity = 1; }    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }     $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop     } // close foreach loop } ?> <?php 


  if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] !=
  "") {
      // Access the array and run code to remove that array index   $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];     if
  (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);     } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);  } } 
?> 
<?php 


  $cartOutput = ""; $cartTotal = ""; $pp_checkout_btn = '';
  $product_id_array = ''; if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) ||
  count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
      $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>"; } else {     // Start PayPal Checkout Button
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form
  action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="chowdhurym79@gmail.com">';    // Start the For Each loop  $i = 0;

      foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {         $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products
  WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");        while ($row =
  mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];             $details = $row["details"];         }
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];      $cartTotal =
  $pricetotal + $cartTotal;         setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
          $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);        // Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly        $x = $i + 1;        $pp_checkout_btn .=
  '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $x . '" value="' .
  $product_name . '">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $price . '">
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';       // Create the product array
  variable      $product_id_array .=
  "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].",";       // Dynamic table row
  assembly      $cartOutput .= "<tr>";      $cartOutput .= '<td><a
  href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br
  /><img src="inventory_images/' .        $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' .
  $product_name. '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';         $cartOutput .= '<td>'
  . $price . '</td>';
                $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">      <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity']
  . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id .
  '" type="submit" value="change" />        <input name="item_to_adjust"
  type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />         </form></td>';
        //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $pricetotal . '</td>';      $cartOutput .=
  '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' .
  $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove"
  type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';         $cartOutput .=
  '</tr>';      $i++; 
      }     setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
      $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);  $cartTotal = "<div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart
  Total : ".$cartTotal." USD</div>";
      // Finish the Paypal Checkout Btn     $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">  <input
  type="hidden" name="notify_url"
  value="https://www.yoursite.com/storescripts/my_ipn.php">     <input
  type="hidden" name="return"
  value="https://www.yoursite.com/checkout_complete.php">   <input
  type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">    <input type="hidden" name="cbt"
  value="Return to The Store">  <input type="hidden"
  name="cancel_return"
  value="https://www.yoursite.com/paypal_cancel.php">   <input
  type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">   <input type="hidden"
  name="currency_code" value="USD">     <input type="image"
  src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif"
  name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and
  secure!">     </form>'; } ?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
  Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta
  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Your Cart</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css"
  type="text/css" media="screen" /> </head> <body> <div align="center"
  id="mainWrapper">   <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>  
  <div id="pageContent">
      <div style="margin:24px; text-align:left;">

      <br />
      <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="18%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product</strong></td>
          <td width="45%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product Description</strong></td>
          <td width="10%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>
          <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
          <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Total</strong></td>
          <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Remove</strong></td>
        </tr>
       <?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
       <!-- <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr> -->
      </table>
      <?php echo $cartTotal; ?>
      <br /> <br /> <?php //echo $pp_checkout_btn; ?>
      <br />
      <br />
      <a href="cart.php?cmd=emptycart">Click Here to Empty Your Shopping Cart</a>
      </div>    <br />   </div>   <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?> </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Did you wrote this code in this style? O_o

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: No...i did not write this code in this style

Comment: Looks like someone is fixing the post. See my answer it still applies.

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php notes:

> The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon
>   capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is
>   undefined in Windows.

You may need to check your PHP Config on that Windows server.

Comment: <?php  

$db_host = "localhost"; 

$db_username = "root";  

$db_pass = "";  

$db_name = "ecomerce"; 

 
mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");              
?>

Comment: You asked why you were getting that error you posted. The reason is that it is not defined for Windows Servers. Does that not answer your question?

Comment: "My php config is OK"......so you post DB login code which has NOTHING to do with php's config. You need to reread what Twisty was asking.